# Hazelcast test cases in osgi

Tags: java, osgi, port, hazelcast, testcase

I have a simple question, Am gonna run the junit test cases for hazelcast, In the **test suite** before class part, **am starting the hazelcast server using newHazelCastInstance method in hazelcast, so the server comes up with the default port 5701**, So My assumption is, the hazelcast server will never stop, until I call the shutdown method.

But what happens is, It gets lost, Once my test cases got over, I never called shutdown! Any reason why its happening???

Or Is there a mechanism that once I start the hazelcast server using my hazelcast code, It has to remain open, Unitl I disconnect / shutdown using the code???

Comment: Since you tagged this question with OSGi, how do you run your tests exactly?

Comment: I have 3 test suites, one in each bundle with same name, I have configured the surefire reports with the test suite so all the tests are running, Hope so u are a osgi guy, Could u pls tell me like how to run the integeration test suite in osgi ??

Comment: How to cconfigure that! pls explain with simple examples like Bundle A and Bundle B ....

Comment: I still have no idea how you run the tests. Surefire itself is not related to OSGi, but the generic junit test executor in Maven. Doesn't the server shutdown because the only reference to it is garbage collected when the test is cleaned up?

Comment: Currently, I have three bundles A, B and C... I have individual test suites in each bundle A, B and C, What Am doing is, I gave the test suite reference in pom.xml to run all the three test suite, But the problem is all the three test suites are independently running... Is there a way I can integerate all the tests in 3 bundles as one point of contact

Comment: If u didnt get my point yet! pls tell me like how to achieve unit testing for osgi bundle